# Spring Batch, how to skip an entire Job based on a condition

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a job defined in spring batch like this

```
  @Bean
  public Job myJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, Step firstStep,
      Step secondStep, Step thirdStep) {

    return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(firstStep).next(secondStep)
        .next(thirdStep).build();
  }
```

But I would like to execute the 3 steps of the job only if a specific condition is met without throwing any exception.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance

What I have tried was to define a listener like this

```
public class ConditionCheckerListener implements JobExecutionListener {

  @Override
  public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    if (true) //Add logic for condition {
      jobExecution.setExitStatus(ExitStatus.STOPPED);
      //throw new RuntimeException("Batch Stopped");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    System.out.println("Exit status " + jobExecution.getExitStatus());
  }
}
```

And then add to the configuration of the job the listener like this

```
 @Bean
  public Job myJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, Step firstStep,
      Step secondStep, Step thirdStep) {

    return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .listener(new ConditionCheckerListener())
        .start(firstStep).next(secondStep)
        .next(thirdStep).build();
  }
```

But the issue is that if I only set the exitStatus to STOPPED the other Step gets executed. Only if I throw an exception the job fail and the other steps are not executed.

I would like to be able to stop the execution of the job without throwing any exception.

Is it that possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature request about this here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/4411. It allows you to start a job definition with a decider, in which you can decide to start the job or not.

The feature is merged and will be included in the upcoming v5.1.